# Problema en guardar datos de un array en C

Tags: array, c

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en C muy extenso, en una funcion, debo realizar que si el usuario opta por cargar el carton (Trata de un bingo) de forma manual.
El problema esta en que el numero no puede superar el 90 y no puede ser menor a 0, entonces se me complica realizar esta funcion, pero eso no es todo, se me ocurrio una idea, la lleve a cabo y tengo un problema que CREO que es de memoria o de inicializacion. La funcion es esta:

```
void generarCartonManual (int m[RENGLON][COLUMNA])
{

int i,k;

    for (i=1; i<RENGLON+1; i++){ //Renglones 3
        for (k=1; k<COLUMNA+1; k++){ //columnas 5
                printf("Renglon %d columna %d -> ",i,k);
             scanf("%d",&m[i][k]); //Guarda cada numero introducido por el usuario en la variable m.
             if (m[i][k]>90 || m[i][k]<0 ){
                printf("El numero introducido es mayor a 90 o menor a 0, introduzca nuevamente el numero.\n ");
                printf("Reescribe el numero ---> ");
                scanf("%d",&m[i][k]);
             }
             }
        }
    }
```

Nota: Renglon = 3, Columna = 5.

[image: Problema 1]

Como pueden ver, solo seleccione para generar UN carton, pero al superar el numero 90 el codigo se rompe demasiado, mostrandose 3 cartones generados y todos MAL, alguien sabe cual es el problema en cuestion?

Edito: Acabo de borrar el if, y genere todos los numeros de forma correcta, un solo carton, y lo que se me genero fue lo mismo, me muestra tres cartones y MAL generados.

[image: Problema Dos]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás haciendo los bucles desde 1 y no desde 0. Ten en cuenta que los array en C empiezan en 0

```
void generarCartonManual (int m[RENGLON][COLUMNA])
{

int i,k;

    //Aquí sería i=0, no i=1
    for (i=0; i<RENGLON; i++){ //Renglones 3
        //Aquí sería k=0, no k=1
        for (k=0; k<COLUMNA; k++){ //columnas 5
            printf("Renglon %d columna %d -> ",i,k);
            scanf("%d",&m[i][k]); //Guarda cada numero introducido por el usuario en la variable m.
            if (m[i][k]>90 || m[i][k]<0 ){
            printf("El numero introducido es mayor a 90 o menor a 0, introduzca nuevamente el numero.\n ");
            printf("Reescribe el numero ---> ");
            scanf("%d",&m[i][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Te lo he puesto corregido, espero que eso solucione tu problema.

Comment: Como estás arrancando desde 0, ya no hay que hacer el `+1` en la condición de los for.

Comment: Buena vista, no me había dado cuenta  @eftshift0

Comment: Hola, Te quiero agradecer, Fue un simple cambio estético que hice para que diga Renglón 1, y no renglón 0 al comienzo, pero esto me genero todos estos problemas, y pienso que es porque le "intente" cambiar el valor a una constante. Un mes sin programar absolutamente nada pasa factura, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: El valor al imprimir puedes modificarlo en la línea donde imprimes: `printf("Renglon %d columna %d -> ",i+1,k+1); ` 
Si te he ayudado marca como respuesta por favor!

Comment: @HatoriHanso la forma de agradecer es votando las respuestas como aceptadas.

Comment: Te agradecería que si la respuesta te ayudó la marques como respuesta aceptada, eso siempre motiva a seguir ayudando @HatoriHanso :)

Comment: @Benito-B disculpame no me habia dado cuenta, siempre lo suelo hacer